# User changeable shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, userform

I've created a simply toolbox/dashboard in Visual Studio Express in VB for my work that contains links to all of the software and shortcuts we use on a day-to-day basis (see the image below, company name/app names covered to protect the innocent :p)[image: Order Management ToolBox]

This was originally created for just me, then I modified the code to work on my co-workers computer.  The changes that needed modifying were the addresses for each of the apps.  Say, for example, App 1 is directly on the C:\ drive for me, but for my co-worker it is buried in C:\Program Files\blah blah blah.  I would have to go in and hard code that path for each and every differing app path, and then if something happens and the path changes, I have to recode it again before deploying it.

What I would like to do it something where the user can modify the path so all I have to do is deploy the executable and the user can modify the path on their own.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?  Would it be best to have the executable look for a text file to read from/write to?  Is there an easier and more effective way to do this?  I'm open to any suggestions at this point

Comment: I found a decent tutorial on using StreamWriter/Reader.  Seems to work so far, however how do I parse the string?  The text file I created to reference is all paths (i.e. C:\Windows\blah).  Is there a way I can have the text file say something like "App1 = C:\Windows\blah.exe" and parse the string to only get the path?

Answer (score 0):

If you shellexecute just the program name, it will be looked up in the AppPaths registry key. See `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. Plus it will open anything. If you want to open a text file `a.txt`, register it as `a.exe`. Typing `a` will run the command (`notepad c:\somewhere\a.txt`).

Comment: Can you show an example of a program that isn't standard to Windows?  Say, Google Chrome?

Comment: I don't have google chrome. But you can look in your own registry for examples. All commercial programs use this.

Comment: Why is this tagged VB6 ifyou aren't using. In VB6 GetSetting will get just the path. or the API has ini specific functions (GetSetting has been ported from Win16 inis to Win32 registry). Plus just use split to break on = and 2nd element in array will be the path. The windows way is the correct way not your way.

Comment: I am coding in visual basic,i think you're thinking of VBA. Again, please post some example code. I'm not a code guru and have been learning as I go, telling me what to do doesn't help anything if I don't know how to do what you're saying.

Comment: VBA is the language that VB6 uses. VB6 is just an app object and a forms package, the language is VBA. Plus there is noting I've written that is VBA or VB6 specific, it's general Windows programming, with the assumption of COM, but there is API calls that do the same. Look at wsh.shell object.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  For some reason I thought VB6 was the language version, my bad.  Regarding your method, wouldn't having the .exe search the registry for the application paths cause the .exe to take a while to load, since it is scanning the entire registry?  I'll start looking up the wsh.shell object you wrote about.

Comment: Windows knows where to look and IT LOOKS if you use one of the many shell Executes, Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") : WshShell.Run "winword", 1, false: MS do there best to make things easy. If something is hard you are doing wrong.

Comment: I ran an example using the method you outlined.  It does work, but only for Chrome, NotePad, Calculator, etc.  Apparently the software our acquired company wrote (which this tool links to as an application) doesn't store the exe in the registry and, thus, the program doesn't find it.  Thank you for the suggestion, but at this point the Streamreader/writer method will work just fine and it will cover all applications and tools inside the userform; might as well have the program search for everything the same way rather than have each program be searched a different way.